# Computing Asymptotic Constant for the count of $S_3$-sextic fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently reading this paper counting $S_3$-sextic fields https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-05/S0002-9939-07-09171-X/S0002-9939-07-09171-X.pdf by Bhargava and Wood. I'm trying to verify how they obtained the asymptotic constant for $p = 2, 3$.

My attempt:

$$c_2 =\sum_A \mu_2(A) \frac{D(A)}{D(\bar{A})^{1/3}}$$ where the sum $A$ is over all etale cubic $\mathbb{Q}_2$ algebra $A$, $\mu_2(A)$ is the relative density as defined on the paper on page 3 (or 1583), and $\bar{A}$ is the $S_3$ closure of $A$. To compute $\mu_2(A)$, I referred to Davenport-Heilbronn paper by BST https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0672.pdf Lemma 18 and Lemma 19. To look up all the possible extensions, I went over to LMFDB at https://www.lmfdb.org/padicField/.

For example, if $A$ is the cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with ramification index 3 and inertia degree 1, the relative density would be $\frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(1^3))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}$. The discriminant of $A$, $D(A)$, would be $2^2$ since the discriminant exponent $c=2$, and the discriminant of the $S_3$-closure of $A$ would be $2^4$. I computed this by looking at the Galois splitting model provided in LMFDB, and finding the discriminant of the $p$-part of splitting field.

Doing this for all cubic etale algebra of $\mathbb{Q}_2$, I have that $$c_2 = \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(111))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(12))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(3))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(1^21))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\left(2\frac{p^2}{p^{2/3}} + 4\frac{p^3}{p^{3/3}}\right) + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(1^3))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)} \frac{p^2}{p^{4/3}} =\frac{1+2p^{1/3}+4p+p^{-4/3}}{1+p^{-1}+p^{-2}}$$

The 2 and 4 are because there are 2 quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with $e=2$ and $c=2$, and 4 quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ with $e=2$ and $c=3$. I thought maybe I should replace 2 with 2/6, and 4 with 4/6 since there are 6 quadratic extensions with $e=2, f=1$, but it still does not work. Doing the same for $p=3$, I have

$$c_3 = \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(111))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(12))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(3))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\frac{1}{1} + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(1^21))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\left(2\frac{p}{p^{1/3}}\right) + \frac{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p(1^3))}{\mu(\mathcal{U}_p)}\left(2\frac{p^3}{p^{7/3}} + 3\frac{p^4}{p^{4/3}} + \frac{p^4}{p^{8/3}} + 3\frac{p^5}{p^{11/3}}\right)$$

Additional questions:

1. Is my computation of the relative density correct? Or have I misunderstood the definition from the paper?
2. To compute the discriminant of the $S_3$ closure of a cubic extension $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, is it right to compute the $p$-part of the discriminant of the splitting field of the Galois splitting model of the particular cubic extension $A$?

These are vastly different from what they had on their paper. Obviously, I have a severe misunderstanding/error in my calculation and I would appreciate if someone can point out where my mistakes are in particular.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**It seems like you're on the right track, but there might be a few subtle points where things went sideways. Let's break this down:**

**Understanding Relative Density:**

- **Double-check your understanding of  μ₂(A).**  Bhargava and Wood's definition is rooted in class field theory.  Make sure you're comfortable with how that translates into the Davenport-Heilbronn results, especially how valuations play into it.

**Discriminants and S3 Closures:**

- **Your approach for finding the discriminant of the S3 closure seems sound.**  It's often the most direct way, but it can get calculation-heavy.
- **A subtle point:** Sometimes a cubic extension's discriminant might not change under the S3 closure. If the splitting field already has an S3 Galois group, the p-part of the discriminant remains the same.

**The Mystery of the '2' and '4' Factors:**

- **It feels like you might be conflating counting extensions with weighting by density here.** Those '2' and '4' factors seem to be counting how many extensions have a certain ramification pattern. The μ₂(A) term *already* accounts for the relative probabilities of those occurrences.

**General Tips**

- **Smaller Example:** Try working out a simpler cubic extension in detail, comparing your hand-calculation of all the terms with the paper's result for that specific case. Sometimes, tracing an example highlights where an assumption goes wrong.
- **Literature Lookup:** There might be papers specifically focused on computing these constants that have worked examples. Often these shed light on common calculation tricks.